# Customizing Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I've been researching Mezzanine for some time now, but I haven't found much of tutorials beyond basic installation.
Mezzanine docs contain information on how to customize Page models and adding new content types.

However, what I want to do is utilise existing content types (pages, blog posts)
in different ways.

For example, I want to have custom "blog listing" page beyond basic default blog listing.

How do I even create that - second - blog page in the admin?
How do I set it's template to my, custom template without touching default blog list template?

How do I therefore have 2 different blog listing pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the mezzanine.blog.models.BlogCategory model for your different blog lists. If you are not happy with 'category/' being in the path, you can copy and modify (below) the [mezzanine.blog.urls](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/urls.py#L23-L24) to your project urls.py.

```
url("^%s(?P<category>.*)%s$" % _slashes,
    "mezzanine.blog.views.blog_post_list",
    name="blog_post_list_category")
```

To create category templates, take a look at the [blog_post_list view](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/views.py#L39) and you will see:

```
templates.append(u"blog/blog_post_list_%s.html" %
                          unicode(category.slug))
```

To add a template for category "Foo", copy `mezzanine/blog/templates/blog_post_list.html` to your project  `templates/blog/blog_post_list_foo.html`. The new template will render if you navigate to /blog/foo/.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the series of blog posts on theming Mezzanine by Josh Cartmell. I've found this series to be extremely helpful in getting started with Mezzanine.
[MEZZaTHEMing (creating Mezzanine themes) Part 1: base.html](http://bitofpixels.com/blog/mezzatheming-creating-mezzanine-themes-part-1-basehtml/).